# Responsive Stacking Column Issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I've been trying to figure out how to create a responsive email that will stack two columns on a mobile device, but I keep running into issues. If I get the columns to stack on mobile, they tend to stack on desktop email clients too, instead of being two columns side by side. If I get the columns side by side on desktop, they won't stack right on mobile. It seems like once I get one thing fixed, another thing goes wrong. Can anyone take a look at my code to see if there's something I've missed? It would be greatly appreciated! By the way, I'm using foundation from ZURB as my css file:
http://foundation.zurb.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<!-- Facebook sharing information tags -->
<meta property="og:title" content="%%subject%%" />

<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation.css" />

</head>

<body bgcolor="#f0f1f2" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;     height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; background-color: #f0f1f2; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<style type="text/css">
  #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
  }
  .body{
      width: 100% !important;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  .ExternalClass {
      width:100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div {
      line-height: 100%;
  }
  img {
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  }
  a img {
      border: none;
  }
  p {
      margin: 1em 0;
  }
  table td {
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  /* hide unsubscribe from forwards*/
  blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {
    display: none !important;
  }



  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
            body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

    #preheaderCell{padding:10px !important;}

    #bodyCell{padding:0 10px 0 !important;}

    #footerCell{padding:20px 10px 0 !important;}

    #templateContainer{
      max-width:600px !important;
      width:100% !important;
    }

    h1{
      font-size:26px !important;
      line-height:100% !important;
    }

    h2{
      font-size:26px !important;
      line-height:100% !important;
    }

    h3{
      font-size:16px !important;
      line-height:100% !important;
    }

    h4{
      font-size:16px !important;
      line-height:100% !important;
    }

    #headerImage{
      height:auto !important;
      max-width:600px !important;
      width:100% !important;
    }

    .headerContent{
      font-size:20px !important;
      line-height:125% !important;
    }

    .bodyContent{
      font-size:18px !important;
      line-height:125% !important;
    }

    .footerContent{
      font-size:14px !important;
      line-height:115% !important;
    }

    .button{
      width:30% !important;
    }

    .note{
      font-size:14px !important;
      line-height: 17px !important;
    }



  }
</style>

<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #f0f1f2; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100% !important" width="100%">
    <tbody>
    <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
   <tr>
      <td align="center" id="preheaderCell" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;  margin: 0; padding: 20px;" valign="top">

          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 600px; ">
               <tbody>
            <!-- <tr>
                  <td pardot-region="preheader_content01" align="center" class="preheaderContent" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: center; " valign="top" width="180">
                                    Email not displaying correctly? 
                                    <a href="%%view_online%%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606060; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">View it in your browser</a>.
                   </td>
                 </tr> -->
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <!-- // END PREHEADER -->
    <tr>
        <td align="center" id="bodyCell" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; margin: 0; padding:0 20px 20px;" valign="top">
            <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: separate !important; width: 600px; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ccc;">
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
                        <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #f0f1f2; border-collapse: collapse !important;  mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width:100%!important;" width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>

                            <td bgcolor="#3f7f80" align="left" class="headerContent" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; padding: 16px;" valign="top" pardot-region="header_image"></td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        <!-- // END HEADER -->
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0 20px 0;" valign="top">
                        <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateBody" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" width="100%">

                        <tbody><tr>
                                <td pardot-region="body_content" align="left" class="bodyContent" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #3f4040; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding:25px 0 25px;" valign="top">

                                <h3 style="color: #000000 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;  font-weight: Bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 16px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:15px; text-align: left">Hi, <%First%></h3>         

                                    <h1 style="color: #000000 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 26px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:15px; text-align: left">TITLE</h1>

                                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</span>
<br>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td pardot-region="body_content" align="center" class="bodyContent" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #3f4040; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 21px; text-align: center; padding:0px 0 0px; valign="top">


                                    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
      <br>
        <div>
          <b>dsafhjl dsfhajlk hj hjk hjkds hdfskj:</b><br>
          hdlkjs hfkjlsdhflkjs dhfkjld  shkljfhkla jsh dkljs hfklj dsah kjhfaklj hdflkj shaflk jdshfkjlh sadlfhjlsdakhjf
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
        <div>
          <img src="xxx" alt="" border="0" width="283px" height="180px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

                                </td>   
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img height="25px" src="x" alt="">
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <span class="note" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 200; color: #7e7f80; font-size: 12px; line-height: 14px;"><i>djskhfk dshkjlfh dshfalkj fhdjsl</i></span><br><br>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody></table>


                        <!-- // END BODY -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
                        <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #f0f1f2; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; width:100%!important;" width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#3f7f80" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; -moz-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; -webkit-border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; border-radius:0 0 5px 5px; font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 10px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;" valign="top" pardot-region="header_image">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        <!-- // END HEADER -->
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </tbody></table>
            <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table><br>
```

Comment: man who is going to read all this? shorten your code, make an example

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using Zurb's Ink for this: http://zurb.com/ink/. Foundation for websites isn't made for emails but Foundation Ink is. Also the cool Playground with templates here: http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates.

I created a codepen here in case someone wants to delve deeper into this with real code: http://goo.gl/aCShcF